# Enable Autosave files plugin on Sublime Startup

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, autosave

How can the **AutoSave** plugin for Sublime Text be automatically enabled on Sublime Text 3 startup?

[link to auto-save is here](https://github.com/jamesfzhang/auto-save)

Comment: Can you edit to provide a link to the plugin that you're referring to?

Comment: added the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular package doesn't naively support the idea of enabling itself automatically when Sublime starts, so in order to accomplish this a small plugin is needed to make this happen, which I've posted below.

In order to use this plugin, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu, then replace the stub plugin code that is presented to you with the code below and save the file in the location that Sublime will default to (your `User` package) as a Python file, for example `auto_save_on_startup.py`

***NOTE:*** See the edit below; this plugin requires that you add a setting in order to control whether it's enabled or not.

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

# Sublime executes this every time it loads the plugin, which includes when
# it first starts, as well as whenever the this file changes on disk.
def plugin_loaded():
    settings = sublime.load_settings("auto_save.sublime-settings")
    # See if auto_save_toggle_at_startup is turned on; default it to
    # not being turned on if the setting is missing, because that is
    # how the package would behave if you didn't add the setting.
    if settings.get("auto_save_toggle_at_startup", False):
        sublime.set_timeout(lambda: sublime.run_command("auto_save"), 1000)
```

---

***Edit:*** The original version of this plugin called `run_command` directly; however Sublime invokes the `plugin_loaded` endpoint before it has fully added all of the command classes provided by plugins, so it was possible for this to try to run the command before it was available.

The code above has been modified so that there is a delay imposed before the command triggers to give the commands time to become available.

---

As the comment suggests, every time Sublime loads a plugin file, it will execute the `plugin_loaded()` function inside of that plugin file, if it happens to exist.

Here the code checks the auto save package settings to see if you have set the value `auto_save_toggle_at_startup` to `true`, and if you have it will invoke the command from the auto save package that turns it on.

As such, you also need to select `Preferences > Package Settings > Auto-save > Settings - User` from the menu and add the appropriate setting. Preferences is under `Sublime Text` in the menu if you're using MacOS.

If that brings up an empty file (because you're using the default settings), then you should enter the following into the file and save it. Otherwise you can just add the setting itself to the existing settings.

```json
{
    // Toggle auto save at startup (from User/auto_save_on_startup.py)
    "auto_save_toggle_at_startup": true
}
```

Here the comment is a reminder that this setting is being provided by something outside of the package itself, in case you forget.

Since the plugin command will only toggle the state of the auto save when it's loaded, you either have to add the setting before you add the plugin, save the plugin file to get Sublime to reload it once the setting is in place, or restart Sublime.

Alternatively you can replace the `plugin_loaded()` function to contain only the `run_command` line to unconditionally always toggle the state at startup, but you may want to temporarily stop it from doing that at some point in the future, which you could easily do by just toggling the setting.

Comment: Do you see errors in the Sublime console? Are you sure you added the setting and plugin properly?

Comment: It's important that the plugin be saved as a `.py` file directly inside of your `User` package (that is, `User\my_plugin_file.py` is OK but `User\something\my_plugin_file.py` is not), but apart from that the name doesn't matter at all. Make sure that you've also applied the setting as well, or the plugin won't do anything.

Comment: Strangely this does not work for me. I added a print("hallo") to the plugin and removed the settings check. I see the hallo in the console of sublime, but still autosave is not activated. Furthermore if I type sublime.run_command("auto_save") it does work and autosave is activated. Seems like it does not work to activate it with a plugin

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me on my machine. Does the line that says "hallo" appear after `reloading plugin auto-save.auto_save`? What Build/OS are you using, perhaps I can replicate what's happening.

Comment: I discovered a potential reason why this might not have worked and tweaked the answer above; if you're still interested in this, the new version might work better for you.